# Is there any way we can provide the connection string in run time?

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I'm trying to get the connection string using connectionStringName of the sessionstate providers and try to encrypt and decrypt connection string in runtime. So is there any way where i can get and set connection string in runtime?

```
<providers>
<add name="OracleSessionProvider" 
type="Oracle.Web.SessionState.OracleSessionStateStore, Oracle.Web, 
Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" 
connectionStringName="connectionName" />
</providers>
```